# Uploading images with a progress bar in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am writting a program (web site) which uploads images on the server,displays them and  saves them in a folder. I want to add a progress bar which will be connected to the image's file size while it is being filled.Here is my Default.aspx file

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <br />
        <output id="images"></output>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvPhotos" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField ="Text" HeaderText="filename" />
                        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Value" ControlStyle-Height="250" ControlStyle-Width="250" HeaderText="Photo" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <br /> 

        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                Loading....<br />
                <br />

            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>

    </div>
        <p>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSuccess" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<ListItem> sia = new List<ListItem>();

        if(FileUpload1.HasFiles)
    {

        foreach(var file in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
        { string[] fileName = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"));

        file.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), file.FileName));

            Response.Write(file.FileName + " - " + file.ContentLength + " Bytes. <br />");

            sia.Add(new ListItem(file.FileName, "~/Images/" + file.FileName));

        }


        lblSuccess.Text = string.Format("{0} files have been uploaded successfully.",      FileUpload1.PostedFiles.Count);
    }
        gvPhotos.DataSource = sia;
        gvPhotos.DataBind();

    }
}
```

Please help me in inserting a jquery bar in my Default.aspx. Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe you already seen but this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113418/ASP-NET-File-Upload-with-Progress-Bar) could help